# Powershell Find and Replace in XML with duplicate lines

Tags: xml, powershell

**Goal:**

I want a Powershell script to find and replace text in a singel XML file. But i only want to change one of the parameters in the XML. (see XML below)

Somthing like:

```
(Get-Content C:\test\config.xml).Replace("<Comport>1", "<Comport>2") | Set-Content C:\test\config.xml
```

After a day of googling and reading on Stackoverflow i still cant figur it out.

**Problem:**

The xml file do contain a lot of the same words and sentences.

The XML file will not always contain the same amount of data or lines.

*I cant figure out how to target the right line that contains "comport".*

> excerpt from XML:

```
<Config>
  <utiliti1>
    <Enabled>1</Enabled>
    <Comport>0</Comport>
    <Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
    <Stopbit>1</Stopbit>
    <Parity>NONE</Parity>
    <Databits>8</Databits>
    <IpPort>0</IpPort>
    <IpAdresse>0</IpAdresse>
  </utiliti1>
  <utiliti2>
    <Enabled>1</Enabled>
    <Comport>0</Comport>
    <Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
    <Stopbit>1</Stopbit>
    <Parity>NONE</Parity>
    <Databits>8</Databits>
    <IpPort>0</IpPort>
    <IpAdresse>0</IpAdresse>
  </utiliti2>
  <utiliti3>
    <Enabled>1</Enabled>
    <Comport>0</Comport>
    <Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
    <Stopbit>1</Stopbit>
    <Parity>NONE</Parity>
    <Databits>8</Databits>
    <IpPort>0</IpPort>
    <IpAdresse>0</IpAdresse>
  </utiliti3>
```

Comment: Is the goal to replace all `<Comport>0</Comport>` with `<Comport>0</Comport>`, `<Comport>1</Comport>`, `<Comport>2</Comport>`, etc.? Or is the goal to just target a specific `Comport` value?

Comment: i want to target a specific comport under a specific utiliti. But i do not know what comport number it has

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know which `utiliti*` node to select but know the unique comport value, you can do the following:

```
# Find and replace Comport 20 with 37
$x = [xml](Get-Content C:\test\config.xml)
$x.SelectSingleNode('//Config/*[Comport="20"]').Comport = '37'
$x.Save('C:\test\config.xml')
```

XPATH `//Config/*[Comport="20"]` selects the `Config` element with a child element that contains a child element called `Comport` with a string value of `20`.

---

If you want to replace an unknown number of duplicate `Comport` values with new values, you can do the following:

```
$x = [xml](Get-Content C:\test\config.xml)
$usedComports = @{} # Tracks already seen comports
$newComport = 0 # Current available comport 
$comportNodes = $x.SelectNodes('//Config/*[Comport]')
$comports = $comportNodes.Comport
($comportNodes | Group Comport | Where Count -gt 1).Group | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Comport -in $usedComports.Keys) {
        # Increase $newComport until it is unique among your xml comport values
        do {$newComport++} until ($newComport -notin $comports+$usedComports.Keys)
        $_.Comport = "$newComport" # Using quotes to make it a string
    }
    # Adds current comport to tracker table
    if ($_.Comport -notin $usedComports.Keys) {
        $usedComports.Add($_.Comport,0)
    }
}
$x.Save('C:\test\config.xml')
```

Comment: I know which utiliti i want to change, but i dont know the comport number. Thanks for anwser, sorry for not being precise enough